# How does one test-run a non-main method? [Java, IntelliJ]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, methods

Is it possible to run a non-main method without running the main method (and thus the whole class)?

It seems like this would be useful to test your code while writing an incomplete program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s called unit testing and for Java JUnit would be the most common tool for the job. It will allow you to run single classes or methods. To further help you out, a mocking tool (for example Mockito) will allow you to substitute classes with mocked implementations so you can construct a class without having to construct all the dependencies for real.

Since you mentioned your IDE, IntelliJ (and all IDE’s worth mentioning) have extensive support for JUnit. Usually there is also support for code coverage so you can even see how much of your code is being tested by your tests.